# How to do partial shutdown into BIOS?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, shutdown, reboot, systemd-boot

I'm running a dual boot system on my laptop (both are linux distros).

It takes ~20 seconds from power-on to the UEFI systemd-boot menu where I can select which OS I want to boot into.

Is there a way to partially shutdown Linux into the BIOS or systemd-boot menu without fully powering off then powering on (e.g. `reboot now` or `shutdown -r now`)?

If so, this would save me a lot of time.

Comment: While this is possible in theory, it will be very difficult to implement in practice. You will have to drop out of protected mode (a rather curious trick in itself), then reset the system into the state expected by BIOS on start up. I'd rather take the not so long wait. :-)

Comment: You're probably looking for [`kexec`](https://www.google.com/search?q=kexec). Haven't tried it recently or with systemd, though.